# Локальные переменные для условных операторов

Tags: c++, c++17

Требуется задать переменную, ограниченную областью видимости условного оператора `if` или `switch`. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Что вы уже попробовали сделать, что именно не получается? Приведите [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В c++17 появилась возможность задавать объявление переменной прямо в условном операторе `if` или `switch`. Например:

```
if (int i = 42; cond) { ... }
```

```
switch (SomeType t; var) { ... }
```

Ключевой момент здесь в том, что ветвление выполняется по `cond` или `var`, а не по `i` или `t`.

До c++17 для этих целей приходилось вводить новый блок через `{ }` и выглядело это не очень красиво:

```
{
    int i = 42;
    if (cond) { ... }
}
```

Новый синтаксис имитирует именно такой подход.

Answer (score 7):

В С++ изначально была возможность объявлять переменные в условиях. В C++ 11 эти возможности были расширены введением понятия контекстуального преобразования и возможностью использовать список инициализации в фигурных скобках. Согласно стандарту C++ (6.4 Selection statement)

> 2 The rules for conditions apply both to selection-statements and to
>   the for and while statements (6.5). The declarator shall not specify a
>   function or an array. The decl-speciﬁer-seq shall not deﬁne a class or
>   enumeration. If the auto type-speciﬁer appears in the
>   decl-speciﬁer-seq, the type of the identiﬁer being declared is deduced
>   from the initializer as described in 7.1.6.4.
>
> 3 A name introduced by a declaration in a condition (either introduced
>   by the decl-speciﬁer-seq orthedeclarator of the condition) is in scope
>   from its point of declaration until the end of the substatements
>   controlled by the condition. If the name is re-declared in the
>   outermost block of a substatement controlled by the condition, the
>   declaration that re-declares the name is ill-formed.
>
> 4 The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a
>   statement other than a switch statement is the value of the declared
>   variable contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). If that conversion
>   is ill-formed, the programisill-formed. The value of a condition that
>   is an initialized declaration in a switch statement is the value of
>   the declared variable if it has integral or enumeration type, or of
>   that variable implicitly converted to integral or enumeration type
>   otherwise. The value of a condition that is an expression is the value
>   of the expression, contextually converted to bool for statements other
>   than switch; if that conversion is ill-formed, the program is
>   ill-formed. The value of the condition will be referred to as simply
>   “the condition” where the usage is unambiguous.

То есть вместо выражений в условиях таких предложений как `if`, `switch`, `for`, `while` можно включать объекление переиенной, у которой имеется инициализатор. В предложениях `if`, `for`, `while` значение объявленной переменной контекстуально преобразуется в тип `bool` , и это значение используется в качестве значения условия.

Вы не можете в качестве объявлений в этих предложениях использовать объявления массивов или функций,  а также определять классы или перечисления.

Для `switch` предложения объявленная переменная должна иметь целочисленный тип или тип перечисления, или иметь возможность быть неявно преобразованной к этим типам.

Вот пример объявление переменной в условии предложения `if`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
private:    
    std::string s;

public:
    explicit A( const std::string &s ) : s( s )
    {
    }

    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return s == "Hi";
    }
    void hi() { std::cout << "I'm glad to see you" << std::endl; }
    void bye() { std::cout << "See you latter" << std::endl; }
};

int main() 
{
    if ( A a { "Hi" } )
    {
        a.hi();
    }
    else
    {
        a.bye();
    }

    if ( A a { "Bye" } )
    {
        a.hi();
    }
    else
    {
        a.bye();
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
I'm glad to see you
See you latter
```

В этом примере объявляется класс, у которого имеется явный оператор преобразования к типу `bool`. Поэтому в условии предложения `If` выможете объявить объект класса, которыфй благодаря этому оператору будет преобразован к значению типа `bool`. Этот объект будет ограничен областью видимости оператора `if`.